# Snackbar onDismissed() callback not coming while destroying the activity

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I am creating a snackbar in the activity(with a callback defined for dismissal of snackbar) and **when the snackbar is still shown I am rotating the device**.

So ideally onDismissed() should be called while the activity is being destroyed and new activity is being created for the new device orientation.

But the onDismissed() callback is not coming while current activity is being destroyed.It only comes after the new activity for the new device configuration is created.

Below is the code snippet and logs:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"MainActivity : onCreate");

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_snack);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v,"Snackbar!",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .addCallback(new BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int event) {
                            super.onDismissed(transientBottomBar, event);
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Snackbar dismissed!");
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Logs:

> 05-20 04:16:42.299 12353-12353/com.gururaj.snackbartest D/MainActivity: MainActivity : onCreate
>   05-20 04:16:42.330 12353-12353/com.gururaj.snackbartest D/MainActivity: Snackbar dismissed!

Can someone point out what is going wrong here?

Comment: I see.The idea of flow I have is first activity is destroyed completely, then second activity is created.Suppose I have something important to do in old activity when snackbar is dismissed , but i want to do it before new activity is created , where do you suggest me to do it? in onDestroy of old activity?

Comment: Yeah, that might be a possibility for you, though that all sounds tenuous at best. The regular lifecycle methods - i.e., `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` - should run in the first instance before `onCreate()` in the second; it's just that the `Snackbar` callback is holding an implicit reference to the first instance, so it's not completely destroyed immediately. I didn't phrase that too well before. You could make the `Snackbar` a field, and check its `isShowing()` in one of those lifecycle methods, and do your necessary task if so. Again, though, this sounds a little shaky.

Comment: Thanks , I will check